# RestApi with dependecy injection

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, rest

I have two application in local machine first is client side application and consuming restapi response and second is ASP.net WebApi application.
RestApi does not contains any DI classes. Client Application have DI classes and consuming restapi response and get error, but if i will remove DI concept then it works fine.

**Consuming WebApi from http://localhost:7820/**

```cs
public class Employee : IEmployee
{
string Baseurl = "http://localhost:7820/";

public async Task<IEnumerable<employee>> GetAll(string accessToken)
{
    List<employee> employee_ = new List<employee>();
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            //Passing service base url  
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(Baseurl);

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
            //Define request data format  
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("access_token", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Employee/Get");

            //Checking the response is successful or not which is sent using HttpClient  
            if (Res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                //Storing the response details recieved from web api   
                var EmpResponse = Res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                //Deserializing the response recieved from web api and storing into the Employee list  
                employee_ = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<employee>>(EmpResponse);

            }
            //returning the employee list to view  
            return employee_;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception er)
    {

        return employee_;
    }
}
```

**Web Api Service :**

```cs
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    try
    {
        using (employeesmgmtEntities entities = new employeesmgmtEntities())
        {
            List<employee> list = (
            from a in new employeesmgmtEntities().employees
            select new
            {
              emplId = a.emplId,
              empName = a.empName,
              age = a.age,
              fullAddress = a.fullAddress,
              city = a.city,
              pinCode = a.pinCode,
              mobileNo = a.mobileNo,
              emailId = a.emailId,
              bankName=a.bankName,
              accountNo = a.accountNo,
              ifscCode = a.ifscCode,
              salary = a.salary
            }).AsEnumerable().Select(o => new employee
            {
              emplId = o.emplId,
              empName = o.empName,
              age = o.age,
              fullAddress = o.fullAddress,
              city = o.city,
              pinCode = o.pinCode,
              mobileNo = o.mobileNo,
              emailId = o.emailId,
              bankName = o.bankName,
              accountNo = o.accountNo,
              ifscCode = o.ifscCode,
              salary = o.salary
            }).ToList();
            
            if (list != null)
            { return Ok(list); }
            else
            { return NotFound(); }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    { return BadRequest(ex.ToString()); }
}
```

HttpResponseMessage comes as error

```
{StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Unauthorized', Version: 1.1, 
    Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?UzpcU09GVFdBUkVTLVBST0ZFU1NJT05BTFxFU1NFTkNFXFNJVEVTX1VOREVSLUNPTlNUUlVDVElPTlxTQVVSQUJIXGVtcGxveWVlc01nbXRBcGlcZW1wbG95ZWVzTWdtdEFwaVxhcGlcRW1wbG95ZWVcR2V0?=
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Sun, 10 Jan 2021 13:29:06 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 71
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Expires: -1
}}
```

Comment: The returned error information in your question is not descriptive enough for anyone to help you. Please make sure you get the actual exception information. This can likely be done by changing the exception settings in your IDE or changing how errors are outputted in your development environment. Once found, please post them including the *full* stack trace. As it currently stands, your question needs more clarity, while on the other hand containing [too much unnecessary information](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and will, therefore, likely be closed.

Comment: Thanks Steven for help finally i solve problem is wrong coding. I will mention in my comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mistake in 2 lines of code consuming time restapi that is

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("access_token", "Bearer " + accessToken);

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Employee/Get");
```

Solution is Remove Get and Replace "access_token" keyword to "Bearer"

```
 client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",accessToken);

            //Sending request to find web api REST service resource GetAllEmployees using HttpClient  
            HttpResponseMessage Res = await client.GetAsync("api/Employee");
```